# Squid3 transparent proxy config

Tags: squid

I'm trying to setup a transparent proxy for my network. I'm running a ubuntu server with squid3 installed.

To test it I've added this rule to my laptop. Which is suppose to forward all traffic on port 80 to the squid server.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.135:3128
```

When I try to browse http from my laptop it just times out. The log file on the squid server shows that there has been an attempt made. Access.log is filled with entries like this:

```
1459188490.553 166494 10.0.0.135 TCP_MISS/502 35116 GET http://www.squid-cache.org/Artwork/SN.png - HIER_DIRECT/10.0.0.135 text/html
```

My config file:

```
# ACCESS CONTROLS OPTIONS
# ====================
#
acl QUERY urlpath_regex -i cgi-bin \? \.php$ \.asp$ \.shtml$ \.cfm$ \.cfml$ \.phtml$ \.php3$ localhost
acl all src
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/24 # Your network here
#acl localhost src 127.0.0.1
acl safeports port 21 70 80 210 280 443 488 563 591 631 777 901 81 3128 1025-65535
acl sslports port 443 563 81 2087 10000
#acl manager proto cache_object
acl purge method PURGE
acl connect method CONNECT
acl ym dstdomain .messenger.yahoo.com .psq.yahoo.com
acl ym dstdomain .us.il.yimg.com .msg.yahoo.com .pager.yahoo.com
acl ym dstdomain .rareedge.com .ytunnelpro.com .chat.yahoo.com
acl ym dstdomain .voice.yahoo.com
acl ymregex url_regex yupdater.yim ymsgr myspaceim
#
http_access deny ym
http_access deny ymregex
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access deny purge
http_access deny !safeports
http_access deny CONNECT !sslports
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
#http_access deny all
#
# NETWORK OPTIONS
# —————
#
http_port 3128 transparent
http_port 8080
#
# OPTIONS WHICH AFFECT THE CACHE SIZE
# ==============================
#
cache_mem 8 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 32 KB
memory_replacement_policy heap GDSF
cache_replacement_policy heap LFUDA
cache_dir aufs /home/precise/cache 10000 14 256
maximum_object_size 128000 KB
cache_swap_low 95
cache_swap_high 99
#
# LOGFILE PATHNAMES AND CACHE DIRECTORIES
# ==================================
#
access_log /var/log/squid3/access.log
cache_log /var/log/squid3/cache.log
#cache_log /dev/null
cache_store_log none
logfile_rotate 5
log_icp_queries off
#
# OPTIONS FOR TUNING THE CACHE
# ========================
#
cache deny QUERY
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jp?g|ico|bmp|tiff?)$ 10080 95% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-no-cache ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i \.(rpm|cab|deb|exe|msi|msu|zip|tar|xz|bz|bz2|lzma|gz|tgz|rar|bin|7z|doc?|xls?|ppt?|pdf|nth|psd|sis)$ 10080 90% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-no-cache ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i \.(avi|iso|wav|mid|mp?|mpeg|mov|3gp|wm?|swf|flv|x-flv|axd)$ 43200 95% 432000 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-no-cache ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i \.(html|htm|css|js)$ 1440 75% 40320
refresh_pattern -i \.index.(html|htm)$ 0 75% 10080
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 1440 90% 10080
#
quick_abort_min 0 KB
quick_abort_max 0 KB
quick_abort_pct 100
store_avg_object_size 13 KB
#
# HTTP OPTIONS
# ===========
vary_ignore_expire on
#
# ANONIMITY OPTIONS
# ===============
#
request_header_access From deny all
request_header_access Server deny all
request_header_access Link deny all
request_header_access Via deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
#
# TIMEOUTS
# =======
#
forward_timeout 240 second
connect_timeout 30 second
peer_connect_timeout 5 second
read_timeout 600 second
request_timeout 60 second
shutdown_lifetime 10 second
#
# ADMINISTRATIVE PARAMETERS
# =====================
#
cache_mgr ninja
cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy
httpd_suppress_version_string on
visible_hostname ninja
#
#ftp_list_width 32
#ftp_passive on
#ftp_sanitycheck on
#
# DNS OPTIONS
# ==========
#
dns_timeout 10 seconds
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
#
# MISCELLANEOUS
# ===========
#
memory_pools off
client_db off
reload_into_ims on
#coredump_dir /cache
pipeline_prefetch on
offline_mode off
#
#Marking ZPH
#==========
#zph_mode tos
#zph_local 0x04
#zph_parent 0
#zph_option 136
### END CONFIGURATION ###
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: Have you configured ip forwarding?  'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'

Comment: yes thats done also in /etc/sysctl.conf